# How did Lori survive?

Tags: plot-explanation, total-recall-2012

During the destruction of The Fall, we see Quaid and Melina jump off, but I don't recall seeing Lori jump off of the machine.  Was there a scene of Lori jumping off and I just missed it somehow?  How did Lori survive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They showed her looking at an emergency exit similar (if not the same one) to what Quaid and Melina used to climb to the top of the machine. It shows her looking through the exit door and seeing the machine falling, and that she is running out of balconies to jump out on. Then, the scene changes and you are left to assume that she jumped out of the emergency exit, or didn't make it (which we know she did).